# Two Excel tables created from SQL queries collide in formula auto-fill

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with two SQL queries each returning data to a separate worksheet as a named table. They return the same db fields, but one is constrained on the values of one of the fields. I have additional columns using formulas to transform these field data, and these are also identical between worksheets.

Upon refresh, Excel autofills the formulae per the conventions of a named table. One of the sheets/tables--call it `Table 1`-- autofills with native references (e.g., for a field/column named `variable`, the corresponding formula uses `[@[variable]]` as its reference. However, the other table--call it `Table 2`--autofills with references to `Table 1`, i.e., `'Table 1'[@[variable]]`.

I have searched and replaced these several times, and rewritten the formulae, but each time I refresh the data query these references pop up. I searched to replace `Table 1` with `Table 2`, as it occurred to me this may be a namespace collision and Excel just takes the first-created table as canon. This, though, doesn't fix the issue, nor did changing the column names to create a non-colliding namespace.

The only other thing I can think is that I'd copied the formulas from `Table 1` and even though I *removed* the table name perhaps Excel has held onto the reference. Is there a table cache or such that Excel references to keep pulling these? Should I create a new query and new table and manually create the formulae, or would that run into the same issue?

Comment: +1 for a well-written question. Are your autofill columns part of your tables? I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with the formula column part of the table or not (in Excel 2010 or 2007).

Comment: Thank you. The tables consume the autofill columns, so, yes, they're members of the tables. I can move the formula-laden columns outside the tables but that defeats the autofill behavior, which is key as these workbooks will sit on my clients' desktops and they want to point-and-click minimally to get results. I intend to recreate them entirely from scratch tomorrow and will report back.

Comment: Creating the relevant tables from scratch results in no such namespace collision nor any wonkiness thus far, as we'd expect. I realized that I'd left something out of my initial question: I had copied, in whole or part (likely whole), the tab containing `Table 1` to create `Table 2`. Even editing the resulting new SQL query and the formulae on `Table 2`, it seems Excel--in its effort to help--*recalls* several components of the table and does not update this cached information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Entering this as an answer so it's not shown as an outstanding question.]

Creating the relevant tables from scratch results in no such namespace collision nor any wonkiness thus far, as we'd expect. I realized that I'd left something out of my initial question: I had copied, in whole or part (likely whole), the tab containing `Table 1` to create `Table 2`. Even editing the resulting new SQL query and the formulae on `Table 2`, it seems Excel--in its effort to help--recalls several components of the table and does not update this cached information.